# Mist 0.8.5 & Geth 1.5.0

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, blockchain, mining, ether

Current Mist is 0.8.5 and it runs geth 1.4.17. How can I initial geth 1.5.0 by Mist 0.8.5 without manually start Geth 1.5.0 first ? It's all to do with instruct geth that chaindata is on an external storage by issue --datachain option and bypass the default location if started with Mist.